# Assigning true/false values to Smarty variables

Tags: logic, smarty

I'm trying to assign a false value to a Smarty variable but whenever I test for it, it yields true value.

I've the following assignment:

```
{assign "access" false}
```

However, when I test its value:

```
{if $access}
   You've access
{/if}
```

It tests true.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you cannot use shorthand for booleans.

You need to use:

```
{assign "access" value=false}
```

or

```
{assign var="access" value=false}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on smarty 3, you can just write:

```
{$access=false}
```

Comment: Coolz! 9 more symbols